# How to set a cell size in Android grid view?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to make a gridview with large icon for an app but I couldn't find any tutorial about modifying a cell size on a grid layout on android. Can anyone give me an example or a link about it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like the other [adapterViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) ,on gridView (which extends adapterView) the size that is determined of the children is based on the size that they want to become  , as written in the android API:

> An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `android:numColumns="2"`

Comment: I guess it mostly depends on the size of each item of gridview