# 2D Array grid on drawing canvas

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am writing an pixel art app that paints images the user draws on the screen to pixel look. There are two ways to approach it. Either pixelate the image after saving or have a grid before hand so the user draws the pixel image. I don't find anything on the later method. So my issue with the first is drawing a grid where if a cell is touched I would change the color of it. I tried drawing rectangles on a canvas but that was pointless because i couldn't control the cells.

I was thinking about nested for loops that creates a bitmap at each cell?

Comment: A simple way to do this is to subclass a `View` and override the `onDraw()` and `onTouchEvent()` methods.

Comment: I have done all that. The problem is the actual construction of the grid.

Comment: Determine cell width from `View` width and the number of columns, loop through the number of columns, and draw a line from top to bottom. Do the same for horizontal lines, with cell height and the number of rows.

Comment: Then it becomes difficult to check whether that cell was clicked. I have tried the line drawing already.

Comment: The problem with that is I want an array to hold values of whether that cell is touched or not. Can't do that if I just drawrect.

Comment: So just keep a member Array with dimensions set to the number of columns and rows, and set its values after the column and row have been resolved in `onTouchEvent()`.

Comment: If the dimensions of my grid expand then so does the conditional clauses to check if its within the column and row.. it ia a way but seems like its exhaustive.

Comment: There are no `if`s needed to resolve the column and row. Simply re-calculate `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` whenever the number of columns or rows change, or when the `View` dimensions change.

Comment: That would be great if you could. I am still searching the various ways to implement it before making a decision.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following is just a simple, illustrative example. It is not optimized, implements no exception handling, etc.

```
public class PixelGridView extends View {
    private int numColumns, numRows;
    private int cellWidth, cellHeight;
    private Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
    private boolean[][] cellChecked;

    public PixelGridView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PixelGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        blackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    }

    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        this.numColumns = numColumns;
        calculateDimensions();
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return numColumns;
    }

    public void setNumRows(int numRows) {
        this.numRows = numRows;
        calculateDimensions();
    }

    public int getNumRows() {
        return numRows;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        calculateDimensions();
    }

    private void calculateDimensions() {
        if (numColumns < 1 || numRows < 1) {
            return;
        }

        cellWidth = getWidth() / numColumns;
        cellHeight = getHeight() / numRows;

        cellChecked = new boolean[numColumns][numRows];

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        if (numColumns == 0 || numRows == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
                if (cellChecked[i][j]) {

                    canvas.drawRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight,
                                    (i + 1) * cellWidth, (j + 1) * cellHeight,
                                    blackPaint);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < numColumns; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(i * cellWidth, 0, i * cellWidth, height, blackPaint);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, i * cellHeight, width, i * cellHeight, blackPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int column = (int)(event.getX() / cellWidth);
            int row = (int)(event.getY() / cellHeight);

            cellChecked[column][row] = !cellChecked[column][row];
            invalidate();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's a simple `Activity` for demonstration:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PixelGridView pixelGrid = new PixelGridView(this);
        pixelGrid.setNumColumns(4);
        pixelGrid.setNumRows(6);

        setContentView(pixelGrid);
    }
}
```

Comment: these won't draw an equal dimension of a square.

Comment: @Polar Yeah, no, I didn't say it did. It was just a very simple example to show how to use `Canvas` methods and `onTouchEvent()` to do a clickable grid. It's relatively trivial to make them square, though. `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` just need to be equal. You could simply replace one with the other in the example, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

```java
public class PixelGridView extends View {


//number of row and column 

    int horizontalGridCount = 2;


    private Drawable horiz;
    private Drawable vert;
    private final float width;



    public PixelGridView(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PixelGridView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        horiz = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE); horiz.setAlpha(160);
        vert = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE); vert.setAlpha(160);
        width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0.9f, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        horiz.setBounds(left, 0, right, (int) width);
        vert.setBounds(0, top, (int) width, bottom);
    }





    private float getLinePosition(int lineNumber) {
        int lineCount = horizontalGridCount;

            return (1f / (lineCount + 1)) * (lineNumber + 1f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
       // drawTask.start();
        int count = horizontalGridCount;
        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
            float pos = getLinePosition(n);

            // Draw horizontal line
            canvas.translate(0, pos * getHeight());
            horiz.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, - pos * getHeight());

            // Draw vertical line
            canvas.translate(pos * getWidth(), 0);
            vert.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(- pos * getWidth(), 0);
        }
        //drawTask.end(count);
    }
}
```

and in your main activity:

```kotlin
//inside on create method

        val myView = PixelGridView(this)

        id_frame.addView(myView)
```

`id_frame` is frame layout in xml

[image: example]

Comment: This one worked for me , accepted answer was crashing

Answer (score 1):

This view class will draw grid of equidistance lines in Canvas based on how much GAP_WIDTH_DP is allocated

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;

public class PixelGridView extends View {

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;
    public static final int GAP_WIDTH_DP = 62;
    private float GAP_WIDTH_PIXEL;
    private  Paint paint = new Paint();

    public PixelGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public PixelGridView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);

    }

    public PixelGridView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public PixelGridView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
        return dp * ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {

        // set paint color
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        // get view dimentions
        getScreenDimensions();

    }

    private void getScreenDimensions() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        //gap size in pixel
        GAP_WIDTH_PIXEL = convertDpToPixel(GAP_WIDTH_DP,  getContext());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        getScreenDimensions();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw Horizontal line from Y= 0 -> Y+=Gap... till screen width
        float verticalPosition = 0;

        while (verticalPosition <= screenHeight) {

            canvas.drawLine(0, verticalPosition,
                           screenWidth, verticalPosition, paint);

            verticalPosition += GAP_WIDTH_PIXEL;

        }

        // draw Vertical line from X=0 -> X+=Gap... till screen Height 0|||hor+gap|||W
        float horizontalPosition = 0;

        while (horizontalPosition <= screenWidth) {

            canvas.drawLine(horizontalPosition, 0,
                    horizontalPosition, screenHeight,paint);

            horizontalPosition += GAP_WIDTH_PIXEL;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One available option is to look into using the [Android Gridview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) as the drawing grid; I have not tested this myself, however if you create an object to be touched in each cell with your desired pixel dimensions, you should be able to create a rudimentary Pixel Art application by saving the variables.

Note, grid view cells are sized based on their contents, as noted in [How to set a cell size in Android grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003318/how-to-set-a-cell-size-in-android-grid-view)

Also, when it comes to drawing things, there are many different ways to handle it, however following a guide or tutorial such as http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-touch-interaction--mobile-19202 is generally the best place to start and pull what you need from it.

Good luck!

Comment: the grid view was an approach but it adjusts fixed the number of rows and columns I would have. Also there would be lots of imageviews if I had say 100x100 grid.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe stretched 1x1 images, particularly repeating entries, should not have an overly averse affect on memory usage, particularly in contrast to an individual image of equivalent sized image.

As for the fixed rows and columns, you should be able to set the width of each cell to be (desired # cells / Screen Width), of course compensating for any borders and other variables affecting the number. You should be able to dynamically set the number of cells per row as well if variable.