# Android PixelGrid OnDraw Check/Track Current Position

Tags: android, grid, android-canvas

I am currently following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842550/2d-array-grid-on-drawing-canvas). As from this answer, it shows that the pixel/grid will be checked if it has been touched. However, I would like to check a grid as a start point and have controls/button at the mainactivity to move the start point around. For example, if user clicks on move forward button, the start point will move forward, checking the new grid and setting the previous point as white. Now i am getting nullpointerexception upon the checkedCell[column][row] in the moveForward() method

So, here is my code:

```
public class PixelGridView extends View {
private int numColumns, numRows;
private int cellWidth, cellHeight;
private Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
private boolean[][] cellChecked;

public PixelGridView(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public PixelGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    blackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

public void setNumColumns(int numColumns)
{
    this.numColumns = numColumns;
    calculateDimensions();
}

public int getNumColumns()
{
    return numColumns;
}

public void setNumRows(int numRows)
{
    this.numRows = numRows;
    calculateDimensions();
}

public int getNumRows()
{
    return numRows;
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    calculateDimensions();
}

private void calculateDimensions()
{
    if (numColumns == 0 || numRows == 0)
        return;

    cellWidth = getWidth() / numColumns;
    cellHeight = getHeight() / numRows;

    cellChecked = new boolean[numColumns][numRows];

    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    if (numColumns == 0 || numRows == 0)
        return;

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
        {
            if (cellChecked[i][j])
            {
                canvas.drawRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, (i + 1) * cellWidth, (j + 1) * cellHeight, blackPaint);
            }
        }
    }       

    for (int i = 1; i < numColumns; i++)
    {
        canvas.drawLine(i * cellWidth, 0, i * cellWidth, height, blackPaint);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * cellHeight, width, i * cellHeight, blackPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return true;

    int column = (int)(event.getX() / cellWidth);
    int row = (int)(event.getY() / cellHeight);

    cellChecked[column][row] = !cellChecked[column][row];
    invalidate();

    return true;
}
public void moveForward() {
//set column and row to be checked at [1][1] upon button click on mainactivity
    int column = 1;
    int row = 1;
    cellChecked[column][row] = !cellChecked[column][row];
    invalidate();
}
}
```

and here is my activity to call the moveForward() method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
PixelGridView pgv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pgv = new PixelGridView(this);
    pgv.setNumColumns(20);
    pgv.setNumRows(15);

}

public void onBtnForwardPressed(View view) {
        pgv.moveForward();
    }
}
```

and here's the log:

```
05-10 00:36:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(8414): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 00:36:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(8414):     at com.test.PixelGridView.moveForward(PixelGridView.java:131)
05-10 00:36:33.388: E/AndroidRuntime(8414):     at com.test.MainActivity.onBtnForwardPressed(MainActivity.java:281)
```

moveForward() method to move robot:

```
if (currentAngle == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
                if (cellChecked[i][j]) {
                    column1 = i;
                    row1 = j;

                }
            }
        } 
        cellChecked[column1][row1] = !cellChecked[column1][row1];           
        cellChecked[column1+1][row1] = !cellChecked[column1+1][row1];
        invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PixelGridView` object you're creating with `new` isn't in the Activity's layout, as you've not added it. If you've defined a `PixelGridView` in the `activity_main` layout, then you should assign it to `pgv` using the `findViewById()` method. If you meant to create it programmatically, then you should add it to the Activity's layout using the `addContentView()` method.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! You saved my day!!! using findViewById() and casting PixelGridView works! Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry to ask you again. If in the grid view, i want to move right, i would have to turn the current checked cell to right, then move forward, you have any idea how is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yup i am currently keeping track of the checked cell column/row. but it's more of like a robot movement, instead of directly moving to right, it should turn to face right, then move forward.

Comment: sorry for my bad english >< for example in the grid view example you gave, at starting point [0][0], the robot is pointing towards the right, and by moving forward, it is [1][0]. so from there, if i want to move the robot the right, it should turn to face the right, then move forward. I am not sure if you get my question though. >< sorry!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm still not following. How are you indicating that the robot is facing right? With the current code, it's just a rectangle.

Comment: Yup. I just thought about it as well. is it possible to set an angle tied together with the rectangle?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but the implementation is really going to depend what your overall goal is. One possibility is to change the array to an `int` array, with something like `UNCHECKED = 0`, `UP = 1`, `RIGHT = 2`, etc. And then draw, as a simple example, an arrow that shows which direction it's facing based on that value. If the robot's only ever going to occupy one space at a time, you could dispense with the array, and just keep track of the current position and direction. It really just depends on your design.

Comment: But how do I draw an arrow that shows the direction using the onDraw? Yup, the robot is only going to occupy one space at a time. I have no idea how to get this implemented though. :(

Comment: However you want to draw it. You could use `drawLine()` methods to draw a crude arrow, or you could use `drawBitmap()` to draw an image, or `drawText()` with Unicode characters, etc.

Comment: Sorry, another question >< what if my robot occupies 4 grids/spaces at 1 time? and it moves? do i check column/row [0][0], [0][1], [1][0], [1][1]?

Comment: It depends. How far does it move? If one step is the width/height of the robot, then yeah, you'll have to uncheck all four previously occupied cells. If it's only moving one cell in a given direction, then you'll just need to uncheck two of the previous cells.

Comment: I have added in how i use the move forward method in my code above. that code is to check/uncheck 1 cell. basically, how do I check/uncheck the 2/4 cells? i'm a little lost and confused. :/

Comment: @Winona I really don't know where you're heading with this, but I'd probably create a `Robot` class that has fields that hold the cell positions currently occupied. Then, when it moves, just have it uncheck all those first, the set them all to the new ones. Also, I don't mean to be rude, but the mods are gonna get mad if we keep talking in comments. SO is meant to be a one question, one answer kind of format. Please post new questions if you've further problems, but keep in mind that they should be specific and focused. Otherwise, you'll get downvoted and possibly have them closed.