# Draw grid as background android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, grid, background-image

I'm new to android studio and currently working on a game app. I want to set a grid looking as my background of the game. I know how to setup background by simply import a image. But I want to know is there a better way to do it (i.e draw it in a View class) and how would I do it. So if anyone has any experience on that it would be great help!

Comment: I have a very simple [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842550/2d-array-grid-on-drawing-canvas/24844534#24844534).

Comment: Thanks, I modified on it and it works beautifully!