# How can I make a pixel grid in android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, grid, pixel

I want to make a table, or something like a pixel grid, in android to make a years-in-pixels application.

I want to make 365 grids and the background color of each grid must be customizeable.
So it should kinda be able to work like a button.
It doesn't matter if it is not a button, only if it works as I want it to be.

Which layout should I use?

grid layout? Or Table layout? or anything else?

(Actually I tried table layout, but after making almost 350 grids, my computer turned a little bit slow. So I thought it wasn't the best idea)

I've seen this question but it was written in java so couldn't get help. But I want the similar thing with what this guy wants.
[2D Array grid on drawing canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842550/2d-array-grid-on-drawing-canvas)

I'm a real beginner and don't know much about kotlin,,, So it would be grateful to give me any ideas, even very simple ones.